# Rails form doesn't create single params hash with input value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, parameters, form-for

I am having a little trouble with a form in Rails. (I'm new to Rails)

What I get after submitting the form is this:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
name: Jim
email: Jim@jim.com
subject: hello
message: goodbye
controller: contacts
action: create
```

It should be like this:

```
contact:
    name: Jim
    email: Jim@jim.com
    subject: hello
    message: goodbye
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Here is the form (minus all the bootstrap divs and spans):

views/contacts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@contact, url: contact_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, name: "name", value: nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter full name' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, name: "email", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter email address' %>
    <%= f.text_field :subject, name: "subject", class: 'form-control',
        placeholder: 'Enter subject' %>
    <%= f.text_area :message, name:"message", class: 'form-control', rows: 6, placeholder: 'Enter your message for us here.' %>
    <%= f.submit :submit, class: 'btn btn-default pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
  get  'contact'   => 'contacts#new'
  post 'contact'   => 'contacts#create'
```

controllers/contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact]) #<-- always fails because no :contact
    if @contact.valid?
      if @contact.send_mail
        # todo
      else
        # todo
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = params.inspect
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

models/contact.rb

```
class Contact 
  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :name
  attribute :email
  attribute :subject
  attribute :message

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of   :email, with: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  validates_presence_of :subject
  validates_presence_of :message

  def send_mail
    ContactMailer.form_message(self).deliver_now
  end

end
```

I have tried using form_for(:contact), routing with resources, changing the model to use the mail_form gem, but still no luck. Of course I could just get all values by doing params[:name] etc. but it bugs me that isn't creating a single hash with all form input values. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you're overriding rails' default naming structure by having things like `name: "name"`.

Comment: You're right! I added those because bootstrapValidator wouldn't grab the inputs for validation. I removed them and the debugger is showing the :contact hash. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `name: '...'` option, because the helpers already set the name and it's not the one you are setting. In your case, rails will expect that the fields are named like `contact[name]` and `contact[email]` instead of the ones you are setting.

Comment: Whops, I did not see @japed commented. Ignore my answer then.